# The way to count TPS in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I've done some researches at [jmeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) official site, I can not find any specification about TPS(it shows [Throughput](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html)). Can u guys help with giving exact specification about how can I count my web server TPS. I've done some performance tests with jmeter(4.0). Currently I have 2 idea about how to count TPS:

```
1. The total number of threads(users)/Average response time;
```

The start duration of the total threads must be `1` second. If data as below and the average response time is 0.3s, so the TPS is:
`1000/0.3 = 3333 transection per second`
[image]

```
2. The active threads at a certain time/Average response time of all these active threads
```

Say I have data as below:

The chart shows a duration of stable pressure hit server, 3 clients in total have 1050 threads at any time of the duration, so the TPS is(if the average response time is still 0.4s): `350*3/0.4 = 2625 transection per second`
[image]

I have above question because:

**if I start 1000 threads(users) in 1 second, I can not make sure the 1000 threads hit the server at a same time, what if some of them like 10% finished and the others just started? Then the server does NOT get the pressure at a certain time.**

Just help me out pls, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Try increasing number of loops in the [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) otherwise you may (and will) run into the situation when some threads have already finished their job and had already been shut down while others have not been yet started. Good practice is setting number of loos to `Forever` or `-1` and limiting test duration via "Scheduler Configuration" or [Runtime Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Runtime_Controller). Check out [JMeter Test Results: Why the Actual Users Number is Lower than Expected](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-test-results-why-actual-users-number-lower-expected) article for more comprehensive information.
2. The actual number of transactions per second depends on your application response time. If you want your test to generate desired TPS rate it's better to consider [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) and [Throughout Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/) combination.
3. You can check how many transactions per second your test generates using i.e. [Transactions Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/TransactionsPerSecond/) listener or equivalent chart of the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)

   [image]
4. [According to JMeter Best Practices you should be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider upgrading.

Comment: Thanks for ur response. So Transactions Per Second listener shows the TPS of the server during a past time duration? The way to calculate TPS is **Transactions in a time duration/Average response time duraing the time**?